# different color for certain item in my list

Tags: android, state, addition, drawable, states

I have a list with items, some items can be in 'viewed' status. i want those items to have different background color then the rest.

list view basically has a single selector for the whole list, setting a background color on one of the items prevent wont do the trick since the selector is drawn below my item's layout as background and counts on them being transparent.

is there a way to define more then one selector for a list ? if not is it possible to create a selector that has an extra state ? basically all i want is the regular list selector plus an extra state that it's ColorDrawable is defined in my colors.xml.(since i can't inherit from a drawable and the list_selector drawables of android are not visible in the SDK for me to use i wanted just to add a state, but then how do i enforce using the extra state ?)

Comment: ok i discovered the problem is not in the selector.
all i want is a list with two different colors for items like gmail app has for read\unread items. again the issue is that once i set a background on a certain item the selector is not visible anymore.Any idea how i can change item's aplha level on selection or press event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.
My problem is not the state of the selector, i want the selector in the same state for ALL items!
the problem is that i want  the item to be regular if certain boolean in items in the adapter is false and color X if the boolean is true, but even if the color is X i still want it to be transparent once it's selected or pressed.

So the solution is the following xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/viewed_hotels_color" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

i found out the even though the list itself is the one that gets the state , it DOES pass the state on to it's children (I.E the list items) which i thought it didn't do.
Only android:focused wont be effective here, android list items are not focused but selected... so as you can see in any state that is not pressed or selected i give my default color, otherwise it's transparent and the selector is visible to all.

in my adapter i need the following code(in getView() method):

```
View itemView = convertedView; <- i'll spare you the layout details...
Item item = getItem(position);
if( item.isViewed() ){
    itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.viewed_item_background);
}else{
    itemView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
}
```

this makes sure every item will get the right background. of course if an item state is changed to viewed and i want it to show i need to call notifyDatasetCahnged() on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom subclass of your `Adapter` and override the method [`getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29). As this method is called by the list to get the `View` for a single item you can define how the a single list item looks like by overriding `getView()`. So changing the background color of an already viewed item shouldn't be a problem.

**UPDATE**

The [`AbsListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html) class which the `ListView` class extends has a method called [`setDrawSelectorOnTop()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setDrawSelectorOnTop%28boolean%29). I think you can use it to control the behavior of the selector.

Comment: i just explained why this doesn't work, when uyou set the background opf the view you create in getView() you create a situation in which that item will no longer seem to be pressed or selected since the selector draws itself UNDER the view and counts on the view's background to be transparent. Please read before answering the obvious.

Comment: Ups, then I misunderstood you question. Sorry for that.

Comment: What about returning a View with a half transparent background. I know that this solution is not perfect, but better than nothing.

Comment: thanks for the update Flo, tried it before, it only puts the selector on TOP of you View, since the regular selector is not translucent you can't see ANYTHING, just the list ornage color... i can override the methof of course but i'm pretty sure that's not the place i can change the selector's state.

Comment: Mh ok, this problem seems to be really weird.